# LDAP Query to exclude local proxyaddresses

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to write an LDAP Query which excludes all the proxyaddresses from an user object which end in .local. I wrote a query like this `(!(proxyAddresses=*@*.local))`, however this removes all addresses from users which have a proxyaddress ending in local. I have been looking on the internet for days, however I didn't come up with a working solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Can you add some prceisions here ? You are quering AD to retreive users whom attribute proxyAddresses do not end with '.local' ?

Answer (score 0):

An LDAP query allow you to retreive objects where attibutes match some values. For each object you can retreive the attributes you want but if an attribute is multi valued you can't select in a query the values you want. You retreive all the values for an attribute or none. You client program need to sort the result to eliminate the adresses you don't want.

Comment: Additionally, keep in mind this is going to be a slow query. The ! operator removes the index from the equation.